# fetch column value of particular row

Tags: php, mysql

I need to fetch a particular column value of a particular row using PHP in MySQL.
Here is an example, check this imag
I want to fetch the `mostOnline` and its value, I've tried this below code but doesn't work

```
<?php
    $query = $forumdb->prepare("SELECT variable FROM smf_settings WHERE Value = 'mostOnline' LIMIT 1");
    $query->execute();
    $result = $query->fetch();
?>
<div class="media-body">
<p id="greet" align="left">Total Members: <?php echo $result ?> <p>
</div>
```

I'm pretty sure I've done some mistakes, how could that be fixed and be shown?
I'm using PDO by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$query = $forumdb->prepare("SELECT variable FROM smf_settings WHERE variable = 'mostOnline' LIMIT 1");
$result = $query->fetch();
print_r($result);
echo $result['value'];//this should echo 211
```

Comment: To fetch both value and variable: 'Select variable, value...'

Comment: print_r($result) and tell me. does it dump the values you want?

Comment: @aimme this is the output when i print `Array ( [variable] => mostOnline [0] => mostOnline [value] => 211 [1] => 211 )`

Comment: its an array. so its correct. returning the row you want :)

Comment: now you need to access the array values like this . echo $result['varaible']; and $result['value'];

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to fetch data from Value column where the *value* is `mostOnline`. Which is definitely not correct.

```
 "SELECT variable FROM smf_settings WHERE Value = 'mostOnline' LIMIT 1"
```

Try this:

```
$query = $forumdb->prepare("SELECT variable, value FROM smf_settings WHERE variable = 'mostOnline' LIMIT 1");
```

In your HTML:

```
<p id="greet" align="left">Total Members: <?php echo $result['value'];?> </p>
```

Note the improper closing `</p>` tag in your code too.

Output:

```
Total Members: 211
```

Comment: And when i print this is the output `Array ( [variable] => mostOnline [0] => mostOnline [value] => 211 [1] => 211 )`

Comment: @DavidDejan Isn't that the required outcome? If you want to only show the value i.e. `Total Members: 211`, you need to echo it `$result['value'];` only and not the `$result`.

Comment: @DavidDejan I'm glad it helped. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

your code is incomplete because you have to bind the result like this:

```
<?php
    $data = 'mostOnline';  
    $result = 0; // if database connection or error default is 0 
        if ($query = $forumdb->prepare("SELECT variable FROM smf_settings WHERE Value=?  LIMIT 1")) {
        $query->bind_param('s', $data);
        $query->execute();
        $query->bind_result($variable);
        $query->store_result();
        $selected_rows = $query->num_rows;

        if ($selected_rows > 0) {
           while($query->fetch()) {
           $result = $variable;
           }
        } else {
        $result = 0;
        }
        $query->free_result();
        $query->close();
        }

    @$forumdb->close();
?>

<div class="media-body">
<p id="greet" align="left">Total Members: <?php echo $result; ?> <p>
</div>
```